# BigQuery 'Request contains an invalid argument' when trying to schedule a Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a query that shows the expected behavior when executed manually. When I try to create a scheduled query from it, I always get the error `BigQuery error in query operation: Request contains an invalid argument`. It is 1:1 the same query except that I want to schedule it.

Both the Web Platform and the CLI display the same error **`BigQuery error in query operation: Request contains an invalid argument.`**. Even `--apilog=stdout` returns nothing meaningful to me.

We use a similar scheduled query in another table - the only difference is that the target and origin location in the new query is `--location=europe-west3` instead of `us`.

**Command:**

```
bq query \
--append \
--display_name=XXX \
--schedule='every 24 hours' \
--destination_table=XXX \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
'[...]'
```

**Stdout:**

```
INFO:googleapiclient.model:--request-start--
INFO:googleapiclient.model:-headers-start-
INFO:googleapiclient.model:content-type: application/json
INFO:googleapiclient.model:accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
INFO:googleapiclient.model:accept: application/json
INFO:googleapiclient.model:user-agent: google-api-python-client/1.7.10 (gzip)
INFO:googleapiclient.model:-headers-end-
INFO:googleapiclient.model:-path-parameters-start-
INFO:googleapiclient.model:parent: projects/XXX/locations/-
INFO:googleapiclient.model:-path-parameters-end-
INFO:googleapiclient.model:body: {"destinationDatasetId": "III", "displayName": "scheduledQueryName", "schedule": "every 24 hours", "scheduleOptions": {"disableAutoScheduling": false}, "dataSourceId": "scheduled_query", "params": {"query": "[.........]", "write_disposition": "", "destination_table_name_template": "[.........]", "partitioning_field": ""}}
INFO:googleapiclient.model:query: ?authorizationCode=&alt=json
INFO:googleapiclient.model:--request-end--
INFO:googleapiclient.discovery:URL being requested: POST https://bigquerydatatransfer.googleapis.com/v1/projects/XXX/locations/-/transferConfigs?authorizationCode=&alt=json
INFO:googleapiclient.model:--response-start--
INFO:googleapiclient.model:status: 400
INFO:googleapiclient.model:content-length: 285
INFO:googleapiclient.model:x-xss-protection: 0
INFO:googleapiclient.model:x-content-type-options: nosniff
INFO:googleapiclient.model:transfer-encoding: chunked
INFO:googleapiclient.model:vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
INFO:googleapiclient.model:server: ESF
INFO:googleapiclient.model:-content-encoding: gzip
INFO:googleapiclient.model:cache-control: private
INFO:googleapiclient.model:date: Tue, 19 Nov 2019 14:06:45 GMT
INFO:googleapiclient.model:x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
INFO:googleapiclient.model:alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
INFO:googleapiclient.model:content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
INFO:googleapiclient.model:{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}

INFO:googleapiclient.model:--response-end--
BigQuery error in query operation: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Any clue what **`BigQuery error in query operation: Request contains an invalid argument.`** can cause?

Comment: us only has us-west1 and us-west2. there's no us-west3 so this is invalid.

Comment: You speak about location europe and us. Set the location to `eu` instead of europe-west3

Comment: The origin as well as the destination table is located in 'eu-west3'

Answer (score 1):

```
BigQuery Data Transfer Service does not yet support location europe-west3.
Please select a dataset in a supported location.
```

You have to change the location to `EU`